# How to serialize access to an asynchronous resource?

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcp

Can anyone point me to a good working solution to the following problem?

The application I'm working on needs to communicate over TCP to software running on another system. Some of the requests I send to that system can take a long time to complete (up to 15sec).

In my application I have a number of threads, including the main UI thread, which can access the ***service*** which communicates with the remote system. There is only a single instance of the service which is accessed by all threads.

**I need to only allow a single request to be processed at a time, i.e. it needs to be serialized, otherwise bad things happen with the TCP comms.**

**Attempted Solutions so far**

Initially I tried using lock() with a static object to protect each 'command' method, as follows:

```
lock (_cmdLock)
{
SetPosition(position);
}
```

However I found that sometimes it wouldn't release the lock, even though there are timeouts on the remote system and on the TCP comms. Additionally, if two calls came in from the same thread (e.g. a user double clicked a button) then it would get past the lock - after reading up about locking again I know that the same thread won't wait for the lock.

I then tried to use  AutoResetEvents to only allow a single call through at a time. But without the locking it wouldn't work with multiple threads. The following is the code I used to send a command (from the calling thread) and process a command request (running in the background on its own thread)

```
   private static AutoResetEvent _cmdProcessorReadyEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
   private static AutoResetEvent _resultAvailableEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
   private static AutoResetEvent _sendCommandEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

   // This method is called to send each command and can run on different threads
   private bool SendCommand(Command cmd)
    {
       // Wait for processor thread to become ready for next cmd
       if (_cmdProcessorReadyEvent.WaitOne(_timeoutSec  + 500))
            {
            lock (_sendCmdLock)
                 {
                 _currentCommand = cmd;
                 }

            // Tell the processor thread that there is a command present
            _sendCommandEvent.Set();

            // Wait for a result from the processor thread
            if (!_resultAvailableEvent.WaitOne(_timeoutSec  + 500))
                _lastCommandResult.Timeout = true;

        }
        return _lastCommandResult.Success;
    }

 // This method runs in a background thread while the app is running
 private void ProcessCommand()
    {
        try
        {
            do
            {
                // Indicate that we are ready to process another commnad
                _cmdProcessorReadyEvent.Set();

                _sendCommandEvent.WaitOne();
                lock (_sendCmdLock)
                {
                    _lastCommandResult = new BaseResponse(false, false, "No Command");
                    RunCOMCommand(_currentCommand);
                }

                _resultAvailableEvent.Set();

            } while (_processCommands);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _lastCommandResult.Success = false;
            _lastCommandResult.Timeout = false;
            _lastCommandResult.LastError = ex.Message;
        }

    }
```

I haven't tried implementing a queue of command requests as the calling code expects everything to be synchronous - i.e. the previous command must have completed before I sent the next one.

**Additional Background**

The software running on the remote system is a 3rd party product and I don't have access to it, it is used to control a laser marking machine with an integrated XY table.

I'm actually using a legacy VB6 DLL to communicate with the laser as it has all the code for formatting commands and processing the responses. This VB6 DLL uses a WinSock control for the comms.

Comment: it controls a laser! Is it attached to sharks' heads?!? Do you have a mini-me? ;)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why a queueing solution wouldn't work.

Why not put each request, plus details for a callback with result, on a queue ? Your application would queue these requests, and the module interfacing to your 3rd party system can take each queue item *in turn*, process, and return the result.

I think it's a cleaner separation of concerns between modules rather than implementing locking around request dispatch etc. Your requestor is largely oblivious of the serialisation constraints, and the 3rd-party interfacing module can look after serialisation, managing timeouts and other errors etc.

Edit: In the Java world we have BlockingQueues which are synchronised for consumers/publishers and make this sort of thing quite easy. I'm not sure if you have the same in the C# world. A quick search suggests not, but there's source code floating around for this sort of thing (if anyone in the C# world can shed some light that would be appreciated)

Comment: I totally agree with the queuing solution.

Comment: Yes, go with a queuing solution, it has the added benefit of making it possible to monitor the number of waiting requests in an easy manner.

Comment: There is a potential timing issue with queuing, for example I need to move the laser to a particular position, turn it on and then sent out a separate command over RS232 to read the power of the laser from another device. If I put the requests on a queue I won't know when it will be executed and I then can't coordinate it with the power meter readings.

Some of the commands return data (e.g. get XY position) when I then need to use in subsequent commands, so I really need to execute just a single command at a time.

Comment: So perhaps a) your commands aren't *just* your TCP based commands, but RS232 as well (using a Command pattern or similar) b) you wouldn't queue a command until the callback from a previous command gave you that XY information ?